# Combine common properties in JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to add a common property in my JSON Object. Here is the sample JSON object

```js
results = [
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'India',
    TOTCOUNT: 20,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'India',
    TOTCOUNT: 4,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'China',
    TOTCOUNT: 8,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'India',
    TOTCOUNT: 6,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'Japan',
    TOTCOUNT: 2,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'Japan',
    TOTCOUNT: 4,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'China',
    TOTCOUNT: 2,
  },
];
```

The sample result expected is to add TOTCOUNT field for repeating MKTUNIT properties as follows:

```js
results = [
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'India',
    TOTCOUNT: 30,
  },

  {
    MKTUNITID: 'China',
    TOTCOUNT: 10,
  },

  {
    MKTUNITID: 'Japan',
    TOTCOUNT: 6,
  },
];
```

Comment: Have you considered [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{
  "MKTUNITID": "India",
  "TOTCOUNT": 20,

}, {
  "MKTUNITID": "India",
  "TOTCOUNT": 4,

}, {
  "MKTUNITID": "China",
  "TOTCOUNT": 8,

}, {
  "MKTUNITID": "India",
  "TOTCOUNT": 6,

}, {
  "MKTUNITID": "Japan",
  "TOTCOUNT": 2,

}, {
  "MKTUNITID": "Japan",
  "TOTCOUNT": 4,
}, {
  "MKTUNITID": "China",
  "TOTCOUNT": 2,
}, ];

var x = arr.reduce((result, {
  MKTUNITID,
  TOTCOUNT
}) => {
  result[MKTUNITID] = result[MKTUNITID] ? result[MKTUNITID] + TOTCOUNT : TOTCOUNT;
  return result;
}, {});

let result = Object.keys(x).map(d => ({
  MKTUNITID: d,
  TOTCOUNT: x[d]
}));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First get all unique keys, than iterate over it, and filter & reduce results total count.

```js
const results=[ { "MKTUNITID": "India", "TOTCOUNT": 20,

}, { "MKTUNITID": "India", "TOTCOUNT": 4,

}, { "MKTUNITID": "China", "TOTCOUNT": 8,

}, { "MKTUNITID": "India", "TOTCOUNT": 6,

}, { "MKTUNITID": "Japan", "TOTCOUNT": 2,

}, { "MKTUNITID": "Japan", "TOTCOUNT": 4,

}, { "MKTUNITID": "China", "TOTCOUNT": 2,

},

];

console.log(
  [...new Set(results.map(obj => obj.MKTUNITID))]
    .map(key => ({
      MKTUNITID: key,
      TOTCOUNT: results.filter(obj => obj.MKTUNITID === key).reduce((a, b) => a + b.TOTCOUNT, 0)
    }))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce`.

```js
const data = [{
    MKTUNITID: 'India',
    TOTCOUNT: 20,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'India',
    TOTCOUNT: 4,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'China',
    TOTCOUNT: 8,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'India',
    TOTCOUNT: 6,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'Japan',
    TOTCOUNT: 2,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'Japan',
    TOTCOUNT: 4,
  },
  {
    MKTUNITID: 'China',
    TOTCOUNT: 2,
  },
];

const map = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  result[item.MKTUNITID] = result[item.MKTUNITID] || {
    MKTUNITID: item.MKTUNITID,
    TOTCOUNT: 0
  };

  result[item.MKTUNITID].TOTCOUNT += item.TOTCOUNT;
  return result;
}, {});

const final = Object.values(map);

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `forEach`

```js
results = [ { MKTUNITID: 'India', TOTCOUNT: 20, }, { MKTUNITID: 'India', TOTCOUNT: 4, }, { MKTUNITID: 'China', TOTCOUNT: 8, }, { MKTUNITID: 'India', TOTCOUNT: 6, }, { MKTUNITID: 'Japan', TOTCOUNT: 2, }, { MKTUNITID: 'Japan', TOTCOUNT: 4, }, { MKTUNITID: 'China', TOTCOUNT: 2, }, ];
g={}
results.forEach(o=>!g[o.MKTUNITID]?g[o.MKTUNITID]=o:g[o.MKTUNITID]={MKTUNITID:o.MKTUNITID,TOTCOUNT:o.TOTCOUNT+g[o.MKTUNITID].TOTCOUNT})
console.log(g)
```